# Modify Ubuntu toolchain

Tags: gcc, makefile

In version 11.10 the flag "--as-needed" became default in the Ubuntu toolchain.

Due to many problems I have with undefined symbols at runtime I don't want to change all
the makefiles anymore. I want to remove this behavior from my Ubuntu again.

But i don't find the place in the system where these defaults are set.

So where can I get rid of this behavior system-wide?

Comment: Why not just fix your libraries/applications to link properly so that you don't have to do break the system? If you have undefined symbols issues as a result of --as-needed, then your builds are not correct.